# How do I paste spreadsheet data on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, markdown

What is the best way to copy and paste spreadsheet data on Stack Overflow?

I've looked on the forums, but I can't seem to find a way to copy and paste headers and their column data. The indenting always seems to come out wrong.

The advanced help does not mention putting data in this field.

Comment: why would you need to post large data sheet in a post? You should always provide a minimal example. Keep it to the bare minimum.

Comment: Pasting data is helpful.  I don't see where tom says that he needs to post large sets.  Fixed-column-width works best.  That's the default for R.  I don't know if it's supported by Excel, but probably so since Excel can read fixed-column-width data.  Then you just indent with Ctrl-K.

Comment: Note that unlike [certain other markdown implementations](http://www.reddit.com/wiki/commenting#wiki_tables), SO's markdown does **not** have built-in tables.  You have to use code-formatting and align stuff yourself.

Comment: [Is there any markdown to create tables?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/179419) on MSE may also be helpful.

Comment: Related: [The latest on creating tables using markdown for SO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371772/1595451)

Answer (score 2):

Produce the output with fixed column widths.

You want to paste in a format that can be cut and pasted into another tool.  Fixed-width columns are easily readable by both human and machine, so that is a good format to use.

In comparison, comma-separated is easily machine-readable, but not so good for humans.

R prints in fixed-column-width by default to the screen, which makes cut and paste quite convenient.  For example:

```
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Here, `>` is the prompt character, and I entered the command `head(iris)` to print that part of this table.  Printing this with `write.csv` to get a CSV equivalent results in this output, which is not human-friendly:

```
"","Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width","Species"
"1",5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,"setosa"
"2",4.9,3,1.4,0.2,"setosa"
"3",4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,"setosa"
"4",4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,"setosa"
"5",5,3.6,1.4,0.2,"setosa"
"6",5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,"setosa"
```

Even without all those quote characters, it's difficult to tell what goes where.

Last of all, **please do not put pipe characters between columns**, as is seen in the output from some commands, unless you're demonstrating such a command (e.g., database access from a sql prompt).  That is not more human-readable and makes machine-readability harder.  Here's an example:

```
  | Sepal.Length | Sepal.Width | Petal.Length | Petal.Width | Species
1 |          5.1 |         3.5 |          1.4 |         0.2 |  setosa
2 |          4.9 |         3.0 |          1.4 |         0.2 |  setosa
3 |          4.7 |         3.2 |          1.3 |         0.2 |  setosa
4 |          4.6 |         3.1 |          1.5 |         0.2 |  setosa
5 |          5.0 |         3.6 |          1.4 |         0.2 |  setosa
6 |          5.4 |         3.9 |          1.7 |         0.4 |  setosa
```