# Adding to the help page a list of tools useful to write nicer questions

Tags: support

According to the perfectionistic intent of this community I would suggest to the other users the possibility to make theyr questions and answers nicer by using tools like the following:

- Putting data in textual format: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html
- Running SQL examples: http://sqlfiddle.com/
- Running JS example: jsfiddle.net
- Writing Math text in a pretty format: http://mathurl.com/
- Visio

What do you think, can it be interesting? If you like the idea advice your tools as answers to this question.

Comment: Why should it be SEs responsibility to provide tools for creating graphics? There are thousands of such tools a google search away; I don't see any value in SE creating yet another tool. Also, it's probably nontrivial to specify a set of requirements applicable to all potential use cases, as every question would have different requirements for its graphics.

Comment: @l4mpi: thanks for the answer, of course it's not a responsability of SE to provide something! SE could like it or not. For example SE likes to provide high quality (is not a matter of responsibility). Also I wasn't speaking of creating a tool but of focusing on: "can it be profitable to help our users to make better questions? Could it be achieved by advicing them a list of tool such as Visio, MathJax, Wolfram Alpha and so on?"

Comment: Maybe my question is too much generic, but is there a section where I can ask for a tool for drawing Karnaugh maps?

Comment: Can you please explain the downvotes?

Comment: @Revious - Perhaps people disagree with your suggestion that SE build a special tool just for building graphics of tables. I personally see no reason for them to do so, as that's not core to their business. They have plenty of other things I'd rather they work on before this.

Comment: @BradLarson: ok, I realize that I wasn't clear because that wasn't my suggestion.. My suggestion was to add to the help page a list of useful tools like i did at the end of my question.

Comment: I would suggest that the correct place for many of these links is in the appropriate tag wiki.

Comment: @nkjt: so you agree that it could be useful? I wonder if most of the downvoters have understood what I'm speaking of.. considerated that even Brad couldn't in the first formulation.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that SE needs to get involved here because there ways for us to display data correctly. If you are looking specifically for a way to represent tables, a great tool is [this one](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html).

It allows you to format text as an ASCII table so from an input like this (can't really display the tab character here):

> NULL    1   2 NULL  NULL, updated=true  1, updated=true 2,updated=true 1    1,
>   updated=true  1, updated=true 2,updated=false 2   2, updated=true 1,
>   updated=false 2,updated=true

You can set it as a code block or `<pre>` element to get a rendered result like this:

```
+------+--------------------+-----------------+----------------+
|      |        NULL        |        1        |       2        |
+------+--------------------+-----------------+----------------+
| NULL | NULL, updated=true | 1, updated=true | 2,updated=true |
| 1    | 1, updated=true    | 1, updated=true | 2,updated=true |
| 2    | 2, updated=true    | 1, updated=true | 2,updated=true |
+------+--------------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

By changing the style settings, you can get some nice results:

```
╔══════╦════════════════════╦══════════════════╦═════════════════╗
║      ║        NULL        ║        1         ║        2        ║
╠══════╬════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ NULL ║ NULL, updated=true ║ 1, updated=true  ║ 2,updated=true  ║
║ 1    ║ 1, updated=true    ║ 1, updated=true  ║ 2,updated=false ║
║ 2    ║ 2, updated=true    ║ 1, updated=false ║ 2,updated=true  ║
╚══════╩════════════════════╩══════════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

Comment: What about Matthew's *cri de coeur* [**please do not put pipe characters between columns**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275458/how-do-i-paste-data-on-stack-overflow/275461#275461)?