# The latest on creating tables using markdown for SO post

Tags: support, markdown

Can someone please share a meaningful link on how to create a table for a Stack Overflow question?

Most times when I have a question, I would just type it out as an example (because the real question is a complicated production thing), but they are always mangled.

So I'm using this link:

[How to make tables in good format in asking questions here (which is understandable by others)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220127/how-to-make-tables-in-good-format-in-asking-questions-here-which-is-understanda)

which says to highlight the text and click on the {} from the menu. It's readable but not quite lined up:

```
 col1  col2  col3
 1  apple  red
 2  grape  green
 3  watermelon  pink
```

I see this post

[How to create table in SO Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-to-create-table-in-so-question)

which suggests using this tool:

https://senseful.github.io/text-table/

But that looks like a mess:

+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|               Col1                |    Col2    | NumCol |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
| Value 1                           | Value 2    |    123 |
| This is a row with only one cell  |            |        |
| This row is testing html entities | Te
st |     45 |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+

So, is there something else I'm missing which works to create tables in this forum?

Answer (score 4):

There is [no table formatting as such on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73567/311398). The other post just mentions a workaround using code blocks, you still need to highlight the text and click on the {} from the menu. Therefore, what you are missing is the 4 spaces in front of the table, needed for code formatting. When you add them you'll get a clear table.

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|               Col1                |    Col2    | NumCol |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
| Value 1                           | Value 2    |    123 |
| This is a row with only one cell  |            |        |
| This row is testing html entities | Te<br />st |     45 |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

You can paste the contents into the answer space, highlight the table and click <kbd>Ctrl+k</kbd>. That will format the table as code, and your table

Comment: Or alternatively, [using Unicode](http://marklodato.github.io/js-boxdrawing/).

Comment: It is now possible to create tables in SO posts using the [GitHub-flavored markdown format](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-).